# Use PHP and Windows Task Scheduler to try again on exit(1)

Tags: php, windows-server-2008, scheduled-tasks, exit-code

I use windows task scheduler to start up a php script that works perfectly fine.  Basically `C:\php.exe -f C:\myscript.php`

In my script some work happens that sometimes makes me want to run the task script again in 5 minutes.

I tried to implement this by changing the settings of the task to restart every 5 minutes if the task fails and having my php code `exit(1)`.  The task scheduler seems to know that I exited with an error code of 1, but it does not run the script again.

Does anyone know what I can do to make it so that task manager will try again in 5 minutes if I signal it from my code somehow.

Answer (score 2):

Not an answer to the question as phrased, but might serve as a fallback if you can't get it working: make your job run every 5 minutes, regardless, and then track "last success"/"last failure" yourself, in a database or file.

Before doing anything else, the script can check the logged status, and if there was a failure last time, try again (up to a limited number of tries, presumably). If there was a success last time, exit immediately, unless it's time for the next job anyway (e.g. if the original schedule was daily, then check for `$last_success` being longer ago than 24 hours).